# Changing ADFS 3.0 login page url

Tags: url, adfs, adfs3.0

I would like to change ADFS 3.0 URL from this:

//servername.companyname.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx

to this:
//servername.companyname.com

I had seen this post (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a438b381-0c08-4ebd-bf6e-a41c2d8a5265/changing-adfs-login-page-url?forum=Geneva) but doesn't work for me due to (maybe) I'm using ADFS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

ADFS 3.0 no longer runs on IIS so you have no access to the web site.

It now runs on http.sys.